# Can Wine run Fork, the git client?

Tags: wine, git

I'm new to Linux and the only contact I have had with Wine-like software is through Steam's Proton, which works surprisingly well (though it is taylored for their platform, so it makes sense to work so well).

The thing is that I'm planning on 100% move my operations to Linux (Ubuntu) and that includes my software development operations too. I have a Fork license and the developer says they won't be developing a Linux version, and I quote their exact reply, "until a modern UI library appears on Linux.", whatever they mean by "modern".

That being said, I've never tried random software on Wine. Does anybody know if Fork (or any other software that relies so much in the filesystem) works in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fork is rated as "Garbage" in [Wine's database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=19743), so we can safely assume that it **would not work**. However, free and open source alternatives are available.

[GitHub Desktop](https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/) is an excellent GUI git client, and it works natively (without Wine).

[image: GH]
<sup>Image source: [README](https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop#readme)</sup>

You can enter the following commands one by one to add its repository to your system,

```
wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/gpgkey | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shiftkey-desktop.asc > /dev/null

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list'

sudo apt-get update
```

Then install GitHub Desktop with the command

```
sudo apt install github-desktop
```

Alternatively, you can download the .deb package from https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases and install it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm taking a look at the options and I do like GitHub Desktop. I think I'll go for it. The main reason that made me purchase Fork is that git graph that helps me immediately understand what's going on the repo and GitKraken's paid version is a subscription instead of a single payment like Fork. I suppose I can now instead of that, use the graph in VSCode, through the Git Graph extension, which is pretty good too and use GitHub Desktop for the merges and such

Comment: I have your same issue @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin. I wish we could run Fork on Linux. I have tried out SmartGit which seems to be slightly similar.

Comment: Thanks, @GavinR. I'll check that one out as well!